# Every Smooth Curve Has Length?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\gamma:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}^n$, $\gamma\in C^1$ so $\gamma$ has length which is $$L(\gamma)=\int_{a}^b\|\gamma'(t)\|\,dt$$

Is this a theorem? every smooth curve have a length?

Comment: Every piecewise-$C^1$ curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is rectifiable. Yes, this is a theorem: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Rectifiable_curve

Comment: What do you mean by "have a length"?  It is not meaningful to state this as a theorem unless you have some specific definition for "have a length".

Answer (score 0):

Let $\gamma \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous parametrized curve.  The **length** of $\gamma$ is defined to be
$$\sup_{\mathcal{P}} \sum_{i=1}^n \Vert \gamma(t_i) - \gamma(t_{i-1}) \Vert,$$
where the supremum is taken over all partitions $\mathcal{P} = \{a = t_0 < \cdots < t_n = b\}$ of $[a,b]$, provided this supremum exists.

The theorem is the following: If $\gamma$ is $C^1$, then the length of $\gamma$ exists and is equal to
$$\sup_{\mathcal{P}} \sum_{i=1}^n \Vert \gamma(t_i) - \gamma(t_{i-1}) \Vert = \int_a^b \Vert \gamma'(t) \Vert\,dt.$$